# По какому принципу работает метод сортировки sort в python3

Tags: python, сортировка

Вопрос чисто теоретический. Изучал виды сортировок на парах алгоритмов и структурах данных. Для примера взят язык python3. Я знаю что у него есть метод sort(), и необходимости изобретать велосипед я не вижу. Но хотелось бы знать так ли он эффективен и по какому принципу сортируются элементы в списке ('под капотом').

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=python%20sort%20algorithm

Comment: [Timsort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort)

Comment: @AlexeyTen [Совершенствуйте](https://g.zeos.in/?q=python%20sort%20algorithm) метод :D

Answer (score 1):

Python использует [Timsort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort).

Преимущество алгоритма в том, что в действительности сортируемые массивы часто содержат в себе уже упорядоченные подмассивы и на таких данных *Timsort* существенно быстрее многих алгоритмов сортировки.

Начните заглядывание под капот с этого [Sorting Mini-HOW TO](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).